# Large file getting uploaded multiple times in jquery file upload

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

- I have a referred the example for jquery file upload and created a
  demo app which works fine and i am able to upload files well.
- but the same integration i did in another application and it is not
  working properly the difference here is just that demo had a .erb
  format and this app have .haml format.
- here also i am able to upload files upto 100mb but files above that
  are taking time and in the server log it is displaying "No Memory
  Error - failed to allocate memory". and it again starts uploading.
- and when i refresh the page after cancelling i see the file being
  uploaded multiple times. i am unable to find the proper cause for
  this problem, is it an issue of low RAM and if it is, the same is
  working fine for demo app, i have uploaded upto 6gb through that.
- here is my code

  **application.js**

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var fileUploadErrors = {
    maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
    minFileSize: 'File is too small',
    acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
    maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
    uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
    emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
    };
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload : true,        
    maxRetries : 100,
    retryTimeout : 500,
    fail : function(e, data) {
      var fu = $(this).data('blueimp-fileupload') || $(this).data('fileupload'), retries = data.context.data('retries') || 0, retry = function() {
        $.getJSON('#fileupload', {
          file : data.files[0].name
        }).done(function(result) {
          var file = result.file;
          data.uploadedBytes = file && file.size;
          data.data = null;
          data.submit();
        }).fail(function() {
          fu._trigger('fail', e, data);
        });
      };
      if (data.errorThrown !== 'abort' && data.uploadedBytes < data.files[0].size && retries < fu.options.maxRetries) {
        retries += 1;
        data.context.data('retries', retries);
        window.setTimeout(retry, retries * fu.options.retryTimeout);
        return;
      }
      data.context.removeData('retries');
      $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.fail.call(this, e, data);
    }
  });
  $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
    var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimpFileupload'), 
      template;
    fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
    console.log(files);
    template = fu._renderDownload(files)
      .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
    fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
      template[0].offsetWidth;
    template.addClass('in');
    $('#loading').remove();
  });
  ```

**controller**

```
def index
    @assets = Asset.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @assets.map{|asset| asset.to_jq_asset } }
    end
  end
```

**model**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :upload
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :upload
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  def to_jq_asset
    {
      "id" => read_attribute(:id),
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "content_type" => read_attribute(:upload_content_type),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => asset_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end
end
```

- **index.html.haml**
  I tried to add my index file here but editor is not  accepting it. so that you can refer this [link](http://pastie.org/9057958#58)

For this I have used rails 4, ruby 2.1.0 and for file upload used paperclip and jquery-fileupload-rails gem
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I fixed this issue, I compared gem file for both my demo app and this
  app, and found that the version of rails here is 4.0.2 and in demo
  app it is 4.1.0. So updated this gem and voila everything works
  great.
- also one thing after after updating to 4.1.0 I had an error as
  "undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass" this was due to
  sass-rails. I have to update that as well and with that I also needed
  set sprockets to version 1.11.0 cause after bundle install it gets
  updated to 1.12.0.
- hope this helps someone